# Как сделать, что-бы работала функция while:True и bot.polling()?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно сделать так, что-бы бот отправлял сообщение в заданное время, и при этом что-бы работали команды, возможно ли это, если да то буду очень благодарен если покажете как. ChatGPT мне сказал что такое возможно только на aiogram, сам использую telebot. Если убираю bot.polling(), то как не странно не работают команды, но при этом прекрасно работает отправка по времени, если добавляю bot.polling(), то наоборот, команды работают, а вот отправка по времени нет. Вот сам код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hi')
chat_id = ********
def send_message():
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Привет, как дела?')

schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_message)
schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(send_message)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

    bot.polling()
```

Comment: можно через многопоточность, но лучше реализовать это через асинхронность на aiogramm и aioschedule

Comment: @KJlUK_KJIAK Можете пожалуйста в ответе на вопрос показать как это сделать на библиотеке telebot через многопоточность? Буду очень вам благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже нашел решение

```
def start_polling():
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

polling_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_polling)
polling_thread.start()
chat_id = *******
def send_message():
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Привет, как дела?')
schedule.every().day.at("20:35").do(send_message)
schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(send_message)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```